# Why does spontaneous emission have larger spectral width than stimulated emission in a lasing medium?

Tags: photon-emission

What makes the stimulated emission's spectrum narrower than spontaneous emission's?

[image]

Comment: That diagram makes it pretty clear, IMHO. So are you *really* asking why the laser action threshold > 0?

Comment: I cannot interpret these two diagrams and why the stimulated one is narrower. I cannot see the relation between two .

Comment: The diagrams says that laser action only happens when the intensity $I$ is above the threshold, and above that threshold, the wavelengths are within the range $\lambda_0 - \delta\lambda$ to $\lambda_0 + \delta\lambda$.